Link aherf in email working fine in outlook desktop application, but not clickable in browser or mobile app
While adding a link through ahref tag in HTMl email,it works as expected through outlook desktop application but it is not clickable only while checking it through mobile app or browser outlook.
Not sure what the issue is here.
Is the click/link getting blocked ? How to check the same ?
It doesn't work for Gmail application as well.
I tried removing all the CSS styling for  tag. But still doesn't work.

You need to be a bit more specific than that. Try to look at the raw MIME source of the message in the Gmail mailbox.
